# Can two people master the Elder Wand at one time?

Tags: harry-potter

**What would happen in a scenario where two people try to disarm the master of the Elder Wand at the same time?**

Would the wand change its allegiance to two people or would it's power be broken?

I think the wand would change its allegiance to the more powerful wizard of the two but I require justification.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Why do we have silent downvoters who don't even comment to help the asker improve his/hers question/say what was wrong with it?

Comment: @アズーサ Because it's _yet another_ "what if"-question, concocting a very specific situation, unanswerable from canon or anything even remotely canon-like.

Answer (score 4):

I would say it's pretty impossible for two people to disarm one, no matter what one of the spells would hit first and perform the actual disarming. That is who would master the elder wand.

Answer (score 0):

This question is like [Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat).

The allegiance should be half for both persons.

But in real world it is not possible **at the same time** to disarm anyone by two people.

So as Simon is saying , the first person will be the owner of the elder wand.

Answer (score 0):

No, for two reasons:

> The wand chooses the wizard

and

> However, the Elder Wand knows no loyalty except to strength. So it’s completely unsentimental. It will only go where the power is. (JKR, [PotterCast interview 2007](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1224-pottercast-anelli.html))

As such, the Elder Wand would choose the wizard it deems to be more powerful, and side with them.  If that wizard is killed, then its loyalty will change.